# Collection View (Creating a Draggable UICollectionViewCell) Fatal Error

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to get drag and drop functionality for cells in a collection view. Similar to the one below, except that this one is for a simple UIView:
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/lgdragdrop

To extend this to a Collection View, I am relying on this neat little hack
https://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2014/07/creating-a-draggable-uicollectionviewcell/

Here is the hack
"Create a copy of the contents of the cell as an image, then drag this around the screen underneath your finger."

I have converted the code into Swift:

```
func handlePan(panRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    var locationPoint: CGPoint! = panRecognizer.locationInView(self.collectionView)

    //var locationPoint: CGPoint = panRecognizer.locationInView(self.collectionView)

    if panRecognizer.state == .Began {
        print("Pan Gesture BEGAN")

        var indexPathOfMovingCell: NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(locationPoint)!
        var cell: UICollectionViewCell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPathOfMovingCell)!
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cell.bounds.size)
        cell.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        var cellImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        self.movingCell = UIImageView(image: cellImage)
        //self.movingCell.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.movingCell.center = locationPoint
        self.movingCell.alpha = 0.75
        self.collectionView.addSubview(self.movingCell)
    }
    if panRecognizer.state == .Changed {
        print("Pan Gesture CHANGED")

        self.movingCell.center = locationPoint
    }
    if panRecognizer.state == .Ended {
        print("Pan Gesture ENDED")

        self.movingCell.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}`
```

However, I am getting an error

```
Pan Gesture BEGAN
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

in the following line

```
self.movingCell.center = locationPoint
```

There are other posts related to "unwrapping an Optional value" but didn't help me in my specific case

Please help...

Also, I am not sure if the cell can be dragged outside the collection view. If not, what code needs to be added for that.

Comment: If you drag outside the collection view, the state of the recognizer should change to `.Canceled`. As to the problem at hand, can you add `print("self.movingCell -> \(self.movingCell), location -> \(locationPoint) ")` above the crashing line? It will help you narrow down as to which one of these two is `nil` and then you can investigate further.

Comment: Thank you for your reply
As the recognizer goes to `.Canceled`, how do I override it so that the cell (it's image in this case) can be dragged outside the collection view

Comment: Here is the output for that line. 
`self.movingCell -> nil, location -> (31.0, 25.0)`
Not sure why the image is `nil`
The image of the cell has been copied in the previous line

Comment: Assuming that you added the recognizer to the collectionView, you should add it to its `superview` :) Or more generally speaking - to the `view` property of your view controller (or navigation controller, if you use them and want to include the navigation bar). This will also require you to add additional check in `.Began` state to know if the gesture began in collection views bounds. As to the `nil` - is there any place where you have `self.movingCell = nil`?  Do you know how to use breakpoints in Xcode?

Comment: Also, I am not sure why you wanted me to print `self.movingCell` but not `self.movingCell.center`
So, out of curiosity, I modified your line to 
print("self.movingCell -> \(self.movingCell), self.movingCell.center -> \(self.movingCell.center), location -> \(locationPoint) ")
Interestingly, this time I got the exact same error i.e. `Pan Gesture BEGAN
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)` at this NEW print statement

Comment: Moreover (sorry for so many comments), there is another totally weird issue. When, I first have your `print` statement and then the NEW `print` statement I get the `found nil` error at this statement
`var indexPathOfMovingCell: NSIndexPath = self.emojiCollectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(locationPoint)!`
Unbelievable and crazy...

Comment: Here is where I added the Pan Gesture
`override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                
        panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:")
        self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        
    }`
Hope this is correct. Could you please share the line of code to check the bounds of the gesture.

I know how to use Breakpoints. I have tried adding one at
 `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()`

However, can't see the value of `movingCell` as it was defined as an
`@IBOutlet weak var movingCell: UIImageView!`

Comment: Also, I experimented in StoryBoard with the way I am adding the image view i.e. on screen or with the view controllers (please see the attached image for clarity) and also by putting a dummy image (to avoid nil error). However, no luck... :(
http://imgur.com/a/AM0Ve

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are force unwrapping these two:

```
var indexPathOfMovingCell: NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(locationPoint)!
var cell: UICollectionViewCell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPathOfMovingCell)!
```

You should not do that, as there might be a chance where your finger's location is not currently on any cell, which would return nil. instead, what you should do it leave those as optionals. And safely unwrap them like so:

```
var indexPathOfMovingCell: NSIndexPath? = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(locationPoint)

if let indexPath = indexPathOfMovingCell {

    if let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cell.bounds.size)
        cell.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        var cellImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        // Rest of your code
        ...
    }
}
```

Hope that helps :)

I wrote a post based on the tutorial in Swift, it also contains improvements such as dragging the cell outside of the collection view. You can go check it out [here](http://eatliftswift.weebly.com/technical/creating-a-draggable-uicollectionviewcell).